# How to get an iterateable js array from translation.json

Tags: reactjs, json, translate, i18next

I'm using `react-i18next`.

```
import * as i18next from 'react-i18next';
export const translate:t = i18next.useTranslation(); // no doubt for this because it works for flat object like users.count (which displays 2 as expected)
```

translation.json from `public/locales/en`

```
{
    "users" : {
        "typeA": [
            { "name": "John", "address": "addressofjohn" },
            { "name": "John", "address": "addressofjohn" }
        ],
        "count": 2
    }
}
```

And I pass this `typeA` array to my component.

```
<Component user={translate("users.typeA")} />
```

In my component, when I log that, it displays like below, I can't loop through it.

```
"key 'users.typeA (en-US)' returned an object
```

Tries:

```
<Component user={Array.from(translate("users.typeA")} />
<Component user={JSON.parse(translate("users.typeA")} />
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Here's the documetnation on how to work with arrays in i18next: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays#arrays

Comment: I want to pass the whole array of objects to the props.

Comment: useTranslation is a hook and can't be used outside of a react function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way as in the documentation:

```
<Component user={translate("users.typeA", {returnObjects: true})} />
```